# Windows phone 8.1 HTML5 app , using google map api throws me "permission denied" error

Tags: html, windows-phone-8.1

I was trying to get the user current location on a google map api. I saw a code at this link and thought to give it a try. The code I used is below (all in index.html). But when I run it on emulator it throws me "Permission denied" error. I searched but could not find the reason. Does anyone know if this is supported or am I making any mistake .

Girija

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Geolocation API getCurrentPosition example</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click on the marker for position information.</p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                displayPosition,
                displayError,
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
            );
        }
        else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
        }
        function displayPosition(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var options = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: pos,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: "User location"
            });
            var contentString = "<b>Timestamp:</b> " + parseTimestamp(position.timestamp) + "<br/><b>User location:</b> lat " + position.coords.latitude + ", long " + position.coords.longitude + ", accuracy " + position.coords.accuracy;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }
        function displayError(error) {
            var errors = {
                1: 'Permission denied',
                2: 'Position unavailable',
                3: 'Request timeout'
            };
            alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
        }
        function parseTimestamp(timestamp) {
            var d = new Date(timestamp);
            var day = d.getDate();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = d.getFullYear();
            var hour = d.getHours();
            var mins = d.getMinutes();
            var secs = d.getSeconds();
            var msec = d.getMilliseconds();
            return day + "." + month + "." + year + " " + hour + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + "," + msec;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess I am using the wrong project type, so the geo location does not work